# Only retry delivery on 500 responses

Tags: apache-camel

I only want to retry delivery on `500` errors but can't seem to find a way to limit the scope of the exception to only that status code. My code:

```
onException(HttpOperationFailedException.class)
                .handled(true)
                .maximumRedeliveries(5)
                .redeliveryDelay(200);

.to("http4://localhost:8088/ws/v1/camel?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Camel in Action book (1st or 2nd ed) it has such an example in the end of its error handler chapter.

You just add a onWhen to the onException where you then add a bit of code to check the status code is 500

Comment: After a couple hours of scouring stack overflow I ran across an answer to something else that did that and did that exact thing just a little while ago.